# How do I prevent installer dialog from appearing partly off screen?

Tags: windows, user-interface, windows-installer

Has anybody seen this installer problem where the user runs an uninstall from the control panel, minimizes the window once the uninstall gets underway and then, when he restores the window after the point where the Finish Uninstalling screen would appear, the window shows up partly off screen? Does anybody know how to prevent this from happening? Or is this simply a bug in Windows Installer that we have to mention in our installer's user documentation?

Comment: I have run into this problem as well. Have there been any updated solutions in the past 4 years??

Comment: I also have this problem, did someone have a solution ? do you also have 2 monitors and NVIDIA ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to reproduce this behavior to think about how to address it.

In my installers ( InstallShield and WiX mostly )  if I do a "Remove"  I get a minimal ui experience that doesn't have a minimize button or a finished dialog.  If I do a "Change" and select remove my progress dialog has a minimize but when that dialog is done and the installer switches to a Finished type dialog I get the dialog full size and centered on the screen again as it's a new dialog.